# Spring data mongo with more than 10 parameters

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I want to check if a document with 15 equal fields alredy exists in a collection. And it seems that the `@Query` annotation can not handle more than 10 parameters. The following class throws an exception on calling is duplicated.

```
public interface ReportingentriesRepository extends MongoRepository<Reportingentries, String> {

    @Query(exists = true,value = "{ 'foo': ?0,'foo1': ?1,'foo2': ?2,'foo3': ?3,'foo4': ?4,'foo5': ?5,'foo6': ?6,'foo7': ?7,'foo8': ?8,'foo9': ?9, 'foo10': ?10}")
    boolean isDuplicated(String value0, String value1, String value2, String value3, String value4, String value5, String value6, String value7, String value8, String value9, String value10);
}
```

The exception is:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Could not to find binding for placeholder '?11'.
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ExpressionEvaluatingParameterBinder$BindingContext.getBindingFor(ExpressionEvaluatingParameterBinder.java:341) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ExpressionEvaluatingParameterBinder.replacePlaceholders(ExpressionEvaluatingParameterBinder.java:120) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ExpressionEvaluatingParameterBinder.bind(ExpressionEvaluatingParameterBinder.java:91) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.createQuery(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:130) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:84) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.isDuplicated(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.company.importer.Application.run(Application.java:29) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.company.importer.Application.main(Application.java:22) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
```

Am I missing something or does spring simply not support this?

I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:1.5.1.RELEASE

Comment: I don' think it is because of the number of query paramters. There should be something wrong in the query syntax. @Query can handle more than 10 parameters

Comment: Be my guest and tell me where... I do not have a glue. This is the simpliest querry I can imaging with eleven parameters and it fails.

Comment: from the error message it looks like you are using placeholder '?11' . Put a breakpoint in ExpressionEvaluatingParameterBinder::getBindingFor method and see what values are passed. I could not reproduce this. For me it works perfectly fine even with 15 parameters

Comment: Looks like a bug. Care to file a ticket at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO?

Comment: Opened Ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1677

Answer (score 1):

Spring data has one more annotation which would help to treat the method parameter as query parameter.

> **Annotation: @Param**

This annotation can be used with the method parameter itself. Please find below format which can help to extend the method parameter count to use with spring data.

**Explaination**: You can include N no. of method parameter with **`@Param`** annotation. Please find below valid expression to write annotation.

```
@Param("param0")
```

Now, when you add this @Param annotation with method parameter, you must need to specify parameter in **`@Query`** with the prefix of  `colon (:)`. Something like **param0** in below query,

> @Query("{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{ "match": {"userId":
>   "**:param0**" }}]}}}")

**Complete Example:** You can see org_id is the query parameter.

```
@Query("{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{ "match": {"userId": ":org_Id"}}]}}}")
List<User> getByOrgId(@Param("org_Id") String orgId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already solved this issue, but I was having two different issues, you can check here: [how-to-use-the-same-parameter-for-multiple-conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174921/how-to-use-the-same-parameter-for-multiple-conditions/58189374#58189374)

The first issue is that I want to repeat a parameter, so I tried with `@Param` then I started to got the same error as you which I couldn't use more than 10 parameters.

So I decide to debugging the binding processes and I solve both problems adding a simple single quote to the parameters, like this (check the parameter number 6):

```
@Query(value = "{ companyType: ?0, companyId: ?1, eventType: ?2, " +
            "delivered: ?3, createdAt: { $gt: ?4, $lt: ?5 }, " +
            "$or: [{ $or: [{ $or: [{ $or: [{ requestPayload.sponsorGovernmentId: ?6 }, " +
            "{requestPayload.buyerGovernmentId: '?6'}] }, {requestPayload.supplierGovernmentId: '?6'}] }, " +
            "{requestPayload.invoiceNumber: ?7}]}, {requestPayload.externalId: ?8}] }")
```

After that I'm able to use more than 10 parameters and repeat it.