# How to use the same parameter for multiple conditions

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to compare a value with multiples fields with Spring-Data-MongoDB 1.10.0, I'm using @Query because the nested document is an Object with dynamic fields.

But if I use the same identifier like ?5 in all the conditions, I got an error:

```
exception="com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{ companyType: "SPONSOR", companyId: 6710890, delivered: false, createdAt: { $gt: { "$date" : "2019-09-01T03:00:00.000Z"}, $lt: { "$date" : "2019-09-26T02:59:59.999Z"} }, $or:[ {requestPayload.sponsorGovernmentId: "73068519000185"}, {requestPayload.buyerGovernmentId: "73068519000185"5} ] }
```

I'm trying like this:

```
@Query(value = "{ companyType: ?0, companyId: ?1, delivered: ?2, " +
            "createdAt: { $gt: ?3, $lt: ?4 }, $or:[ {requestPayload.sponsorGovernmentId: ?5}, {requestPayload.buyerGovernmentId: ?5} ] }")
    Page<WebHookDelivery> findByCompanyTypeAndCompanyIdAndDeliveredAndCreatedAtIsBetweenAndAnyKey(String companyType,
                                                                                                  Integer companyId,
                                                                                                  Boolean delivered,
                                                                                                  Date createdAtStart,
                                                                                                  Date createdAtEnd,
                                                                                                  String governmentId,                  
                                                                                                  Pageable pageable);
```

I've tried with only ? and [5].

Is it possible and could anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: We can use same argument for many fields, it is supported and it works fine.
You have some other error with the query you are writing examine it correctly.
Or you post the complete query here.

Comment: @Lucia I updated the question, take a look on the second condition in the OR operator the ?5 turns in "value with a 5 in the end". That's the error. I'm using Spring-Data 1.10.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after debugging the binding process.

I just need to add single quotes in the parameter that I need to repeat, like this:

```
"$or: [{ $or: [{ $or: [{ $or: [{ requestPayload.sponsorGovernmentId: ?5 }, " +
            "{requestPayload.buyerGovernmentId: '?5'}] }, {requestPayload.supplierGovernmentId: '?5'}] }, " +
            "{requestPayload.invoiceNumber: ?6}]}, {requestPayload.externalId: ?7}]
```

So the parameter number five could be use more than once.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Guilherme, that solution can only work for string parameters as using '?0' will convert parameter of any type to string and will give incorrect results.
Passing an extra parameter in the method will same value did the work for me.